# Should we lock questions/responses from downvotes after a period of time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible, or even wise, to stop accepting downvotes on questions and/or responses after a set period of time? Case in point, [here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41245424/4215616) which recently happened to me. This seemingly off-topic question, asked nearly five years ago, recently downvoted my response. Though the question is off-topic, I do prefer to lend a helping and explanatory hand to those who are learning and coming to Stack Overflow for help. I'm nostalgic that way.

See, I am a self-taught programmer and I came to Stack Overflow looking for help where I received it willingly. And if my questions were off, did not make sense, etc. at first, the users prompted/guided me along until I was able to start asking better questions.

Regardless of my experience, I'm sure other find it somewhat ridiculous to come along and find the red -2 on their rep because someone felt it necessary to downvote a question/response of theirs from 5+ years ago. If not lock downvotes, then possibly require an explanation for the downvote (which has been a pet peeve of mine for sometime)?

I agree downvoting is necessary and should inspire the author to take strides in improving their post. And I'm guessing it does more often then not. However, I see little value gained in downvoting a post months after it has been published.

Comment: Why aren't you proposing to lock them from upvotes too? Or demanding an explanation for each upvote?

Comment: This is strictly my opinion, but upvotes are somewhat self-explanatory. Whereas downvotes the author has no idea why the downvote occurred. The very few times I have downvoted, I have tried to explain why I felt the need to do so in hopes of providing some feedback to the author

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: But in this case you do have an idea, you answered an off-topic question. Off-topic questions aren't very useful and it's common that people think that answering them isn't a very useful thing to do either so voters use their votes to try to discourage such things.

Comment: All answers and comments have are very good and well received. Thank you all.

Comment: The age of the post doesn't matter. We must rate content whenever we evaluate it. Locking posts from receiving feedback would be going against the idea of Stack Overflow. In cases, like this where you made a mistake and answered a question you shouldn't have, you can't do anything so you can just ignore the downvotes. You should flag to close the question and maybe with time people will also vote to delete it.

Comment: *"but upvotes are somewhat self-explanatory."* -  Lol, no. I see several posts daily which are worthless and yet receive upvotes

Comment: @PaulStoner - Upvotes absolutely should require an explanation.  Especially some of the upvote to questions that are clearly spam (I have seen this happen)

Comment: Upvotes are not self-explanatory, they feel *nice*. That is what you're after. But nicety has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The opposite could be useful - delay voting (up or down) at the very beginning until a question has had a chance to be improved (or closed/deleted for good due to the author's unwillingness to improve it (before any answers by rep hunters)). Many (initial) downvotes are lazy close votes.

Comment: How many downvotes? This kind of IBR ([Internet background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise) - not literally) is probably not zero.

Answer (score 20):

## No.

Stack Overflow is a collection of questions and answers. People visit Stack Overflow primarily to *find* solutions to their problems and more often than not, land on an existing solution that is more than a year old. Voting allows users to indicate whether or not the content is useful; that indication is important regardless of how old the post is.

Answer (score 11):

Downvoting is not primarily for the post author. It's a signal to anyone reading the post whether it's useful or not. As such we want as much signal as possible.

So sure, feel free to use the downvote as a signal to rereview your post if you wish and make sure it's the best it can be, but if you know a question is off-topic then why answer it at all? Voting or flagging to close it is the course of action you should be taking.

Note that a post's usefulness can change over time as the technology that underlies it ages and also in the case of answers if better ones come along which might have the secondary effect of highlighting the flaws in any existing answers.

Comment: "but if you know a question is off-topic then why answer it at all?", because if the author of the question is way off base about their assumptions of a technology stack, it purposes, and such, isn't it up to us, the community, to at least try and provide some sort of explanation as to why their thinking is off? Even if the question is off-topic, or broad in nature?

Comment: You can always write a comment that points them in the right direction as to how to ask a better question.

Comment: @PaulStoner No, it's not. Stack Overflow is not the place for this. If you want to help people directly you need to use media that allow this, e.g. Discord. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. The close reason you select should link the asker to the help page explaining what is on-topic.